# UIDatePicker inside UITableViewCell not displaying hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker

When I add a `UIDatePicker` into the content view of a `UITableViewCell` in a storyboard, the hour is missing. This does **NOT** happen for some reason if I add the UIDatePicker programmatically.

Here's a screenshot (notice the hours missing):

[image: UIDatePicker Bug]

This is very similar to the problem brought up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755901/uidatepicker-cutting-off-text-not-displaying-days) except I am not messing with `UIAppearance` at all.

Comment: explain it in detail what you need

Comment: @RameshMuthe If you look at the screenshot, it should be pretty clear. The hours is missing.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I made a test project and it only seems to be happening on the iPad.  When running the 5s simulator it shows the hour.

Comment: I tried with a CollectionView and still doesn't show hours on an iPad.  All phone simulators work fine including 6 plus.

Comment: I ended up going with a custom solution using the Picker control.  We ain't got time to let Apple fix this.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem what did you do to fix it?

Comment: @SamB I just end up adding it programmatically

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33390304/3908884

Answer (score 0):

In the XIB file click on the date picker and then look over in the right menu and you can customise the date picker options.

Would probably be worth checking you have got it set to the correct type: Date and Time and nothing else has gone wrong.

Otherwise I would recommend deleting your current one and adding a new one from scratch as that looks very odd

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can refer this [LINK.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html)

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

UIDatePickerModeDate

The date picker displays months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the locale setting. An example of this mode is [ November | 14 | 2014 ].

Comment: Please re-read the question. I am not asking about how to remove the time.

Answer (score -1):

Call `sizeToFit` method to fix this.