# UIDatePicker not displaying properly in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uidatepicker

I am NOT using auto layouts and this is how the UIDatePicker is appearing in my app on iOS 9. The picker is looking flawless in iOS 8 but the problem is only with iOS 9. Any idea how to resolve this.. (P.S using auto layouts in not a solution at the moment for me.)

[image]

Comment: have u added in storyboard or programmatically

Comment: show some more information

Comment: @Uma i have added the picker in the XIB and setting the frame of the picker through code..

Comment: ok.. but in case of storyboard  it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the viewDidLoad() method, change a property of the date picker, for example the mode. Note that, You don't have to leave it changed, you can set it to anything and then change it back to what you actually want.

I am sure, this solution is helps you.