# Datepicker rendered wrong on iPad simulator with iOS 8.1.1 / Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, ios-simulator, uidatepicker

Yesterday I updated to Xcode 6.1.1 and now I'm experiencing some strange behavior. Placing a datepicker in a table view cell causes the datepicker to be rendered strange.

[image: Day is missing and month is cut off]

As you can see the day is completely missing and the month is cut off. This is happening on iPad 2 simulator with iOS 8.1.1. I don't have a device with me to test more.

I filled a bugreport at bugreport.apple.com with the No. 19141277.

Some workaround available?

**Edit:**

Thanks to [cocoanut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25755901/426227) there seems to be a workaround. In my case I wanted the datepicker to be centered in the table view cell. I had a centerX, centerY, height and width constraint. That didn't worked. Now I played with it and the following constraints seems to work:

- Top Space to Content View Equals 0
- Bottom Space to Content View Equals 0
- Align Center X to Content View Equals 0
- Width Equals 320
- Height Equals 216 @ Priority 999

Comment: Please share your radar number in your question and make sure to add a sample project to the radar.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia: I filled out a bugreport at bugreport.apple.com. Is this the same as radar? I included a sample project.

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite a while on this, including trying your constraints workaround, but had no luck.

Eventually I switched to creating the date picker in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` instead of in the storyboard and it worked fine, so I would suggest that to anyone who is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue actually picker not work correctly if we put leading trailing, instead we should put fixed width and height and center with alignments horizontal to superview. 
[image: Apply these constraints]

[image]

[image]