# UIDatePicker not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

Basically this issue started when I updated my app to run with iOS 9.  Without making any change in the code now a white square appears over the picker view, but it works normally.

[image]

Note that the user can hide and show the picker views and the cells they're in.  If you need more info leave a comment.

**UPDATE**: Here is the full screenshot of the Table View:

[image: screenshot]

**UPDATE 2**: The following shows when I preview (press bar space button) the `_pickerView` property in the variables debugger. This makes me think the *strange* view is inside the UIDatePickerView and that it's a bug.

[image: debugger screenshot]

### UPDATE 3: Extensive Research

So I finally did more research using the view inspector and the debugger and I got to some conclusion, although I still don't know how to solve it.
Using the view hierarchy debugger I found out the the *white strange view* it's a `UIPickerTableView` inside the `UIDatePicker`.

[image: White view selected in the view hierarchy debugger]
Here we can see the *subject* selected in blue and it's name at the top of the screen.  I also wrote the whole hierarchy from the picker view to the *subject* so you can see it.

Next step was inspecting my `datePicker` var with the debugger to see if I could get to that `UIPickerTableView` causing problems.  Inside it I could find **3 views, each one corresponding to each component** (day, month, year).  Let me show you the quick look of each one of these:

*Click the pics to enlarge*
[image]
[image]
[image]

In the first and the third one (day and year) we can see what look like some misplaced views next to the actual labels with the numbers.  These properties, as you can see in the screenshot, are `UIPickerColumnViews`.  I didn't go any further but you can imagine that if we inspect that property we would find the *subject* as a `UIPickerTableView`.

After all that I got to the conclusion that the misplacement of those views is what *might* be causing the issue.  And that's all for today.

### FINAL UPDATE

So some days after filing the bug report Apple answered and marked it as a *duplicate*.  So I guess we just have to wait they fix it.  You can check the radar at [rdar://22566989](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4637967612116992)

Comment: "the user can hide and show the picker views and the cells they're in" What does cell refer here to?

Comment: @manish_kumar refers to a UITableViewCell, the picker is in a UITableView.  When the user taps to a *Select Date* cell another one appears right below with the UIDatePickerView.  The behavior is like the one in the Calendar app, when you create an appointment.

Comment: Can you upload a full screen shot of the simulator so that it becomes little more easy to understand?

Comment: @manish_kumar check out the update

Comment: Does your UITableView cell contains any more subviews other than that date picker? If yes, please try out `bringSubviewToFront` method.

Comment: There *shouldn't* be any other subviews other than the date picker view.  I'm gonna try this out anyways and update.

Comment: Use XCode view debugger to see exactly, what is it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Comment: @manish_kumar there are no other subviews in the UITableViewCell and that didn't work.  In the debugger the picker view appears with the white squares, like they're part of it. In the view debugger there are a lot of views that I don't even know what they do.  I start to believe it is an iOS bug.

Comment: I just decided to file a bug report to Apple so they will tell me whether I'm doing something wrong or it's an iOS bug.  You can check out the radar here: [rdar://22566989](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4637967612116992)

Comment: @Hulehule20 "the picker view appears with the white squares, like they're part of it." Does this white square have same frame as it appears in simulator? You can check that out in view inspector.

Comment: Have you tried to dig down date picker view hierarchy to find what this white square is?

Comment: @manish_kumar read my update, I added view hierarchy debugging screenshots.  It has the same frame in the simulator and in the view inspector.  I think it is just misplaced there, above the picker view.

Comment: @Andy Read my update, that's all the information I could gather debuggnig the view and the pickerView property.

Comment: @Hulehule20 I use date pickers on iOS 9 beta without any issues. Maybe this issue you experience is related to date picker being placed in tableview cell. I guess you could check that by making a sample project.

Comment: @Andy I made the sample project, put the date picker in a table view and it displayed correctly.  Maybe it's related with another thing in my environment.

Comment: @Hulehule20 do you use UIAppearance by any chance? I can think of it affecting some of subviews of UIDatePicker.

Comment: @Andy no `UIAppearance` in the whole project.

Comment: @Hulehule20 I'd gradually disable parts of the app until this artifact is gone to find out the cause of this. Categories on UIView are the target number one. Otherwise it's hard to pin point why this happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple Developer Relations marked my bug report as a duplicate, so I guess it is an SDK bug that they'll have to solve.  It is still open by the time of this post (12 Oct).

### Workaround

In the `viewDidLoad()` method change a property of the date picker, for example the mode.  You don't have to leave it changed, you can set it to anything and then change it back to what you actually want.

Comment: Great solution - and it works :) Can't believe that every release has more and more UI bugs.

Comment: I just spent 30 minutes on this BS. Would have spent more time if it wasn't for you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hack that worked for me:  If you change the UITableView separator style to None the problem goes away.  Seems like a bug on Apple's end, like the numerous problems we are finding in iOS 9.9

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  The separators go away (as they should) but the white area bug is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i discover that happened because my UIDatePicker was separate from view of my view controller. I added this view as a sub view in code. To solve this problem, i add the UIDatePicker in viewDidLoad method, this is helped me